# WPF Datagrid Grouping - items with binding converter not updating dynamically

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpfdatagrid

Am new to WPF and using the datagrid control to group items, data is sourced from a java message Q and items are added dynamically as they arrive.

Am using GroupStyle to display the Grouping name, Items Count and a custom converter that reads displays the executed quantity.

The issue I have is that the item count updates as and when items arrive but the custom converter class is not invoked.

```
<DataGrid.GroupStyle>
    ...
 <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}, Count: {1:#0}, Executed Qty: {2}">
            <Binding Path="Name" />
            <Binding Path="ItemCount" />
            <Binding Path="Items" Converter="{StaticResource convertToExecutedQty}" />
        </MultiBinding>
</TextBlock.Text>
.....
</DataGrid.GroupStyle>
```

And in the Converter class:

```
public class ConvertToExecutedQty : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null && value is IEnumerable<Object>)
        {
            IEnumerable<TickOrderViewModel> orders = ((IEnumerable<object>) value).GetBaseElements<TickOrderViewModel>();


            if (orders.Count() > 0)
            {
                var BuyQty = ( from n
                              in orders
                               where n.side.ToUpperInvariant() == "BUY"
                               select n.executed_qty ).Sum();

                var SellQty = ( from n
                              in orders
                               where n.side.ToUpperInvariant() == "SELL"
                               select n.executed_qty ).Sum();

                return BuyQty - SellQty;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

In the above converter, when the tab loads, "orders" count is 1 when there are 2 items that were loaded one after the other as they were read from the MQ.

Ex: I have 2 rows with SELL as 1 and SELL as BUY as 1
Initially on load the collection sees only 1 row, and the executed qty displays -3.

When i switch tabs, then orders now have 2 items and the Exe qty becomes the correct value of -2

any ideas pls?

Answer (score -1):

Personally I have done away with single use converters in favor of putting conversion logic in the properties in my ViewModel.  If however a conversion is expected to be used across several different Views/ViewModels then I put the conversion logic in a dedicated converter.

I imagine you have set a breakpoint in the converter to see when it is being called, and what it's output is?

If so, I would be interested to know when it is called and it's output.  Otherwise, that would be the first step I would take.

It has been my experience that Converters often experience problems that VM Properties do not.

Comment: The grid is grouped by the user on the GUI so not sure if a property might be useful here to get a total count for that specific group. Can i still use properties in this case. Debug seems to hit for all groups but only displays that the collection has one row in it instead of the entire bunch, and when a new row is added, this does not fire.